# Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

*For your perusal and evaluation, I have enclosed my curriculum vitae for further information.*

My main problem with this sentence is the double usage of the word *for*. My idea was to replace it with *with*, would that be better?

Just clarifying: This is at the end of paragraph in which I describe my skills and such.

Comment: As both existing answers indicate, if you're looking for *writing advice*, you'd probably do better simply discarding your first clause *(For your perusal and evaluation)*. But sticking to the specific question asked, the answer is **yes** - you can validly replace your second *for* with the word *with* (or perhaps better, *containing*).

Comment: This doesn’t read very well because of the two (‘for’) prepositions. See the answer by @StoneyB

Comment: I think the sentence reads awkwardly, but certainly **not** because the word _for_ is used twice. Plenty of sentences can use the same preposition more than once without distracting the reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, the second *for* does make it seem an afterthought, which would have led a more careful writer to revise the sentence.

But it is difficult to imagine a context in which both *For your perusal and evaluation* and *for further information* would not be superfluous: why else would you enclose your CV? what else would they do with it?

I suggest that a bare *I enclose my curriculum vitae* tells your correspondents everything they need to know about the document, without impertinently restricting their use of it or suggesting that they require instruction in its use.

Comment: I would totally agree, however, I have to write a letter for an assignment at school, and big words are endorsed, no matter how stupid they sound. I thought this was borderline ok, but I agree. I might completely get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just end without it. It makes perfect sense:

> *For your perusal and evaluation, I have enclosed my curriculum vitae.*

In this context, *for further information* seems redundant.